# Frequent updates

Tags: release-loki

This is not a complaint nor an actual problem for me, I just want to make sure that everything is ok. I am getting a lot of updates, today for example I got 3 or 4. Is that the case for everyone else ?

Comment: Won't add another answer. Just to tell that is the same here for me. I wouldn't mind the frequent updates though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They team is working hard in Denver on the App Center sprint. The updates are likely part of that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question, just an affirmation that today I also got 4 updates. I guess that this was normal.